# Single pixel CSS error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

In my previous question, [CSS Hardware Accelerated Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670303/css-hardware-accelerated-width), I mentioned that I was creating a Phonegap app that includes a feature that will allow you to change the size of a two column layout by moving the middle divider.

I am getting this to work, but I am having some CSS positioning problems. These problems are usually off by one pixel, but I'm sure are just a result of my math. Basically, the two column layout is normally set so that each side is even. Then, if you move the slider, it will change the `left` and `right` values of the columns to either increase or decrease their widths. The resize icon is positioned in between these two columns, and moves with them as their widths change.

The problem, however, is that when you rotate the device, the middle divider changes its positioning by a few pixels. To replicate the problem, you can either:

1. Open page
2. Rotate app
3. Rotate app back to original position

Or:

1. Open App
2. Move slider
3. Rotate app
4. Rotate app back to original position
5. Rotate app

In each case, the middle divider will be off by a few number of pixels, causing it to not align properly with the dividing line.

The JS that runs most of this looks like this:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function (e) {
    var page = $("#columnContainer").width();
    var totalWidth = $("#leftColumn").width() + $("#rightColumn").width() + 2;
    var left = $("#leftColumn").width();
    var test = page - ((parseInt($("#leftColumn").css("right")) * page) / 100);
    $("#columnResizeIcon").css({
        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + (left) + "px, 0, 0)",
        "left": "auto",
    });
    if (totalWidth > page) {
        $("#leftColumn").css("margin-right", "2px");
    } else if (totalWidth < page) {
        $("#leftColumn").css("margin-right", "1px");
    }
    if ($("#leftColumn").width() < 100) {
        $("#leftColumn").css({
            "right": 100 - ((100 / page) * 100) + "%",
            "margin-right": "1px"
        });
        $("#rightColumn").css({
            "left": (100 / page) * 100 + "%",
        });
        $("#columnResizeIcon").css({
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(100px, 0, 0)",
        });
    }
    if ($("#rightColumn").width() < 100) {
        $("#leftColumn").css({
            "right": (100 / page) * 100 + "%",
            "margin-right": "1px"
        });
        $("#rightColumn").css({
            "left": 100 - ((100 / page) * 100) + "%",
        });
        $("#columnResizeIcon").css({
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + (page - 100) + "px, 0, 0)",
        });
    }
});
$("div").on("touchmove", "#columnResizeIcon", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $("#columnContainer").width();
    var left = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    var right = page - left;
    if (left > 100 && left < page - 100) {
        $("#leftColumn").css({
            "right": ((right) / page) * 100 + "%",
            "margin-right": "1px",
        });
        $("#rightColumn").css({
            "left": ((left) / page) * 100 + "%",
            "margin-left": "1px",
        });
        $("#columnResizeIcon").css({
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + left + "px" + ", 0, 0)",
            "left": "auto",
        });
    } else {}
});
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
}

#columnContainer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#000;
}

#leftColumn{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:50%;
    bottom:0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#rightColumn{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:33px;
    z-index: 5;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f5f7 0%,#a7abb7 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, inset 0 -1px 0 #7A8090, 3px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:9px;
    color:#71787F;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #E3E5E9;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.content{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top:42px;
    bottom: 0;
}

#leftColumn .content{
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}

#rightColumn .content{
    background-color:#fff;
}

#columnResize{
    position: absolute;
    width:2px;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-1px;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

#columnResizeIcon{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width:10px;
    height:30px;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top:-15px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-7px;
    border-left:2px solid #000;
    border-right:2px solid #000;
}

#leftColumn,
#rightColumn {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="columnContainer">

    <div id="columnResizeIcon"></div>

    <div id="leftColumn">
        <div class="header">Left Header</div>
        <div class="content"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="rightColumn">
        <div class="header">Right Header</div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would post a fiddle, but the code needs to be run from either the iOS simulator or an actual iOS device, and jsFiddle does not play well with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem is in the margins. I'd get rid of them (hear me out!).

```
#leftColumn, #rightColumn, #columnResize{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    etc...
}
#leftColumn{
    left: 0%;
    width: 50%;
}
#rightColumn{
    left: 50%;
    width:50%;
}
#columnResize{
    left: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

It's a cheap trick, but since your resize bar is only 2px wide, it might as well have the same left pos as the right column. A user wouldn't be able to tell that it should really be 1px to the left. e.g. Depending on the content of the two columns, you may want a margin on the left of whatever is inside the right column.

Comment: That sounds fair. However, you can still give the impression of the columns not touching, for example by giving the column resize div a border. That way your underlying structure is simple (50%/50%) and it will be much easier to make design changes without causing problems.

Comment: Okay, so even if I use borders, the problems that I am talking about are still happening.